# Grammar error in Review

Tags: bug

I was going through reviews this morning, and (yes, just now) noticed an error in a message:

[image: This question doesn't meet a [sic] English Language Learners Stack Exchange guideline.]

> This question doesn't meet a [sic] English Language Learners Stack Exchange guideline.

So this post is to request a correction, that we use "an" instead of "a" there.

Comment: Wow good catch! Thanks for bringing it to our attention! I fumbled around in ELL mod tools and this seems beyond mod ability, so I've just [posted on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354233/grammar-error-in-review-does-this-affect-several-se-sites).

Comment: Ha, same issue on ELU.

Comment: I will pass on this rare opportunity to rip on our sister site.

Comment: The original bug report is one year old today. This still has not been corrected. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349877/349502